# Suppress "Clock skew" warning for future-times in Makefile

Tags: time, makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that does performs a task if it hasn't happened in the last hour.  It does so like this:

```
HOUR_FROM_NOW = $(shell perl -e '($$s,$$m,$$h,$$d,$$M)=localtime(time()+3600); printf("%02d%02d%02d%02d\n",$$M+1,$$d,$$h,$$m);')
NOW_FILE      = $(shell mkdir -p .make; touch .make/now; echo .make/now )

.PHONY: externals
externals: $(PROJECTS:%=.make/proj_%)
.make/proj_%: $(NOW_FILE)
     $(MAKE) -s $(*F)
     touch -t $(HOUR_FROM_NOW) $@

.PHONY: $(PROJECTS)
$(PROJECTS): 
     # do stuff, specifically, clone git-repo if not exists, else pull latest
```

That part works great, except that I now get warnings:

```
make: Warning: File `.make/proj' has modification time 3.5e+03 s in the future
make: Nothing to be done for `externals'.
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
```

Anyone know how to suppress those warnings?  (Or to do a periodic task in a makefile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most versions of touch I have come across can do some date time maths which allows for setting the timestamp of a file directly via the `--date` option.

That and the fact that variables assigned with `:=` are only "evaluated once" makes this a bit easier to read.

```
HOUR_AGO := .make/hour_ago
__UGLY := $(shell mkdir -p .make && touch --date='1hour ago' $(HOUR_AGO))
# The preceding line will be executed once

.make/proj_%: .make/hour_ago | .make
    $(MAKE) -s $(*F)
    @touch $@

.make:
    mkdir -p $@
```

I'm using something very similar to this to periodically refresh login tokens.

Never would have thought of it if it wasn't for Dave's answer though.

---

The directory is created by specifying it as a [order-only-prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the + 3600 is at fault.  What happens if you remove it?

Comment: If I remove it, then it pulls changes every time I run "make".  The whole point is to only pull if we haven't already pulled in the last hour...

Answer (score 0):

I thought and thought, and then the stupid-obvious solution hit me ...

Instead of setting timestamps in the future with HOUR_FROM_NOW, I use the real time and compare with HOUR_AGO_FILE ...

```
HOUR_AGO      = $(shell perl -e '($$s,$$m,$$h,$$d,$$M)=localtime(time()-3600); printf("%02d%02d%02d%02d\n",$$M+1,$$d,$$h,$$m);')
HOUR_AGO_FILE      = $(shell mkdir -p .make; touch -t $(HOUR_AGO) .make/hour_ago; echo .make/hour_ago )

.PHONY: externals
externals: $(PROJECTS:%=.make/proj_%)
.make/proj_%: $(HOUR_AGO_FILE)
     $(MAKE) -s $(*F)
     @touch $@
```

Comment: the  review comment I  is why do you have shell start the command in the sub shell commands. usually a $() spawns a sub  shell. is that make file specific?

Comment: "shell" is a makefile function.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html.  It may look like Bash, but there are some significant differences.  $(shell ...) runs "..." in a subshell.  $(...) is simply a variable reference to a variable named "..." - whereas in bash, $() is the subshell syntax.